# Magento 2: Extension Attributes for Total Model

Tags: extension-attributes, magento2.3.0

I added custom total(discount row) model in cart and checkout summary but it is not getting saved in quote and order. So how to use extension attribute for such total model that works in order, invoice etc. ?